# Exporting schema with Virtual Columns

Tags: database, oracle, import

I am using Oracle 11g XE. I have a schema that contains some tables with virtual columns. The virtual columns look fine in the schema and behave as expected.

I exported a dump of that schema using this command:

```
expdp SYSTEM/SYSTEM schemas=TEST_SCHEMA dumpfile=TEST_SCHEMA.dpdmp
```

and imported it to another database using this command:

```
impdp SYSTEM/system SCHEMAS=TEST_SCHEMA DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=TEST_SCHEMA-2016.DPDMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace LOGFILE=TEST_SCHEMA.log
```

The import went fine but when I checked all the virtual columns they were broken. The DATA_TYPE of the column was wrong, it was `NUMBER` instead of `VARCHAR(36)` and the DATA_DEFAULT function that was there in the original source schema was not in the imported schema, it was just null and when I viewed the actual rows, the value in that virtual column was '44', which was the column id of that column.

Does anyone know why the virtual column did not migrate properly? Do I need to specify something when i'm exporting the schema? Or is this an Oracle bug?

Answer (score 2):

take a look here at BUG#10186633 and BUG#14506804 on the oracle website, there are issues with importing virtual columns.

the problem is that the table is created on import before the Function is created, i believe the workaround is to create the table with the correct definition first and then run the import using the IGNORE flag

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave but i'm not sure if that's the issue here. I haven't created my own function, i'm just using the the UPPER function, not really a user defined function so I thought that should work ok on table creation?

Comment: Also, those bugs seem to relate to issues where people get errors on import. I never got any of those errors on import.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and hope it is applying to the given scenario (without user defined function):

Doc ID 1983171.1,  BUG:18153657: While Importing in 12c database Virtual Column Attributes change (but also manifests in versions older than 12c).

The scenario is virtual column together with 'not null' constraint, the cause they mention is in handling the 'not null' constraint on the virtual column.

As workaround they give the temporary removal of the 'not null' constraint during import.
There's also a patch.